# Example of non-commuting conjugacy classes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $x^G$ denote the conjugacy class of element $x$ in a group $G$ and $x^Gy^G = \{ab~:~a \in x^G, b\in y^G\}$ which contains, but may not equal, $(xy)^G$.  Is there a simple example of a case where $x^Gy^G \ne y^Gx^G$?

Comment: No, they are always equal - try and prove it!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $g^{-1}xg \cdot h^{-1}yh = (g^{-1}xgh^{-1})y(hg^{-1}x^{-1}g) \cdot g^{-1}xg$. So $x^Gy^G=y^Gx^G$.

Comment: Of course - thank you.  The title of [this paper](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jbritnel/Linking.pdf) seemed to suggest that classes need not commute, but in fact the term is being used differently there.

Comment: @DJF - yes absolutely, good observation! The notion of commutativity concerns sets/conjugacy classes, rather than elements.